# How to view gc information of executor in a spark task？

Tags: apache-spark

Why do I set the following parameters, but there is no executor's gc log output, but the driver's gc log can be output normally? Is there something wrong with my parameter setting?Thank you!

```
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Xloggc:/tmp/executor_gc.log \
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps" \
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Xloggc:/tmp/driver_gc.log \
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps" \
```

Comment: Which execution mode: `local`, X + `client`, X + `cluster`?

Comment: i used yarn cluster

Comment: For a first overview, you can check the Executor tab in the [Spark UI](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/monitoring.html)

Comment: @werner 
I tried to view it on spark-ui, but I still can't see the log information. Finally, I set the parameters in the code, and then the log was output normally. I don't know why the settings set when the task was submitted did not take effect?